# Access denied when uploading file using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, authorization, scope

I am using the Sharepoint Online REST API.

I can successfully make the following request:

```
GET /_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/Hello.docx') HTTP/1.1
Host: SITE.sharepoint.com
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
Accept: application/atom+xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

However, when I try to make the below request

```
POST /_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')/files/add(overwrite=true,url='test.txt') HTTP/1.1
Host: SITE.sharepoint.com
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
Accept: application/atom+xml
Cache-Control: no-cache

"hello, world"
```

I get the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</m:message>
</m:error>
```

I am requesting the following scopes:

```
Web.FullControl Site.FullControl AllSites.FullControl List.FullControl
```

Am I missing a scope for this request, or is there some other permissions I need to set elsewhere?

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using?

Comment: @Akhoy Hey, there is no code, this is using Postman to send the requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!

According to [Authentication Code OAuth flow for SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj687470.aspx#Anchor_2):

> the FullControl right is not available ... because an add-in that request permission to access SharePoint resources on the fly can't request full control right

So setting the requested scope to be `Web.Manage` allowed me to upload the file as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you including the the form digest? This is necessary when doing a POST.

To get the form digest in postman first do a POST request with this URL:

`http://yoursite/_api/contextinfo`

You'll get a long string back which you then need to add to the POST request you're trying to make as a Header in the `X-RequestDigest` parameter.

Full details [here](http://tech.bool.se/basic-rest-request-sharepoint-using-postman/).

Comment: Or just go to a SP site and view source to get the request digest. :)

Comment: Yes there are a number of ways to grab the digest value. Since the OP is using Postman, I've described a way for OP to get the digest value from Postman itself.

Comment: Paste `document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value` in the console of your SP site

Comment: @Submits I wasn't including that actually - useful information, thanks. Unfortunately though I have now done this and it still responds with the same error!

Comment: Just try again. The digest value is temporary so you shouldn't wait too long between getting the value and then running your POST query. Failing that, are you sure you don't have read only permissions to the document library?

Comment: For uploading, there are some other issues like file has to be in buffer array, `"Content-Type": undefined` and so one @dav_i

Comment: @Submits I am doing the POST request within 10 seconds of the digest request

Comment: @AtishDipongkor I have tried it with using a stream and defining the Content-Type header too but still get the same error.